# Should an API ever hold anything except a data structure? Or is html in the data fine?

Tags: html, json

Would it be considered code smell to put data into an API that included HTML? Or should it contain exclusively JSON data?

For example would this be acceptable:

```
{
  "id": "redCar",
  "toolTip": "<div class=\"container\"><h3>The Car is red</h3><p>and fast!!!</p></div>"
}
```

Or is there something wrong with storing data like that?

Comment: That is JSON data. That the value happens to be HTML is irrelevant. If your clients need HTML information, then they need it.

Comment: I'd say the HTML should be built on the client from the data